# Where to save user files (OSX Application)?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Where should a Mac OSX application save user files generated in the application? These are not critical files for the program to run, but for example saving a users uploaded avatars, etc.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568708/mac-os-x-where-should-i-store-common-application-data

Comment: What do you need to save avatar image the user has selected for?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend a sub-directory in User's '**Documents**' directory if you'd like to make the data readily available to the user, otherwise an appropriately named sub-directory in User's '**Library/Application Support**' directory is a good choice.

Comment: Application Support?  I don't think so.  I might have agreed before 2012.

Comment: What does 2012 have to do with it?

Comment: Non user document data probably belongs a subdirectory of your app's Application Support folder in the user Library. Or in the App's sandbox if there is one